# Wordpress user specific iframe block

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to build a website where for each user there will be different iframe code. So I want a page where for different user different code will be shown. Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You check if the user is logged in. If logged in, you get the ID of the user. If the ID is some value, display the specific iframe.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( $current_user_id == 3 ):
        // iframe for user with id 3
    elseif ( $current_user_id == 4 ):
        // iframe for user with id 4
    else:
       // default view
    endif;
else:
    echo 'You need to be logged in';
endif;
```